# access mysql on t2.micro from another t2 micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, instances

I have installed mysql 5X in one t2.micro instance. And Installed hadoop in another t2.micro instance.

When i tried to connect to mysql from hadoop its saying connection failure. I am able to ssh between systems. How to make communications possible at application level. Like a java program in one system to insert data to mysql table in another instance.

Comment: Open port 3306 in the security group.

Answer (score 1):

Have you open port 3306 on your instance  for incoming connection from your network ?

Also check if MySQL is bind to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/my.cnf `bind-adress`. You have to change it for 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces.